# Deploying multiple/single instances of a website

Tags: wix, windows-installer, web-deployment, msdeploy

We have an ASP.NET website that we want to deploy (and remove) multiple instances of the site on the same IIS machine.

We also have a few number of customers that need to install the product on their system.

I was hoping WIX would be able to handle this, but it appears you can only have one instance installed at a time.

What options are available to me?  Right now we use FinalBuilder to setup a generic "install package" which uses a batch file that a user populated with their environment settings, and uses tools like sed and awk to update config files and more scripts to deploy to IIS.

It works, but it's very cumbersome. I was hoping to find more of a GUI/command line interface to replace this process.

Comment: Your best bet is to ask [Yan Sklyarenko](http://stackoverflow.com/users/274535/yan-sklyarenko) who has written a [blog post](http://ysdevlog.blogspot.de/2011/08/revisited-multiple-instance.html) about this.

Comment: Multiple instance installations with WiX are quite cumbersome, too. I had to take that path, and WiX supported that much better than other vendors that time. If you don't have to stick with the Windows Installer for this work, I would not recommend that. There are other approaches to ASP.NET application deployments these days (OctopusDeploy?) which might fit better for your case.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like MSDeploy will work for your use case.  It can deploy multiple instances to the same IIS instance and can also delete instances.

The following post is specifically about service versioning but you could use the same technique to install several instances of a web app.

http://www.dotnetcatch.com/2016/03/03/simple-service-versioning-with-webdeploy/